# Installing C++ libraries for VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm kinda new to programming in C++ and programming in general and I have a question regarding the installation and use of libraries, specifically in the context of VSCode. I am using the code that someone has given me for a project, but I don't have any of the libraries downloaded that they are using. These are some of the libraries I need access to:
`#include <sys/socket.h> #include <netinet/in.h> #include <arpa/inet.h> #include <netdb.h>`
When I search them up to download them, the common thing I found for them was the code for them through github. My questions really are how to I download these libraries and when I download them where do I save them on my computer so that I can use them for VSCode and for my projects?

Comment: Some of those (at the very least sys/socket.h) are standard headers on UNIX systems and there are usually packages to install them. Which operating system are you using?

Comment: VScode is just an editor, not an IDE. Therefore it does not come with a C++ compiler, that contains all these headers  by default. There are hundreds of questions about setting up a C++ compiler with VScode and probably hundreds more tutorials if you search for them.

Comment: @ndc85430 so because I am using Windows and the gcc compiler do I have to use some other header file for that library or can I simply just not use that library

Comment: I can't comment on Windows, I'm afraid. I know nothing about development on that platform.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner, I'll share what I know. VS Code likely utilizes Mingw with a compiler named g++ for C++. Mingw includes compilers and linkers with folders, such as "include." You should add library files to this folder for proper inclusion.

Comment: Modifying the compiler installation is usually a bad practice, since it's hard to keep track of what you have done to it. Store your libs separately and specify paths to them with compiler flags. Also VSC can run whatever compiler you want it to, not necessarily mingw.